# Graph the solutions of $ | z-2| + |z+2| < 5 \quad z\in \mathbb{C} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I really don't get how to solve this kind of equations and inequalities on complex numbers. Can someone solve this as an example, or others similars to teach me how to do it please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What geometric locus is that where the sum of lengths of all points from two fixed points is a constant?

Answer (score 1):

You are finding a point on the plane such that its distance to $[0,-2]$ and $[0,2]$ sum to $5$.

What kind of conic curve does that remind you of?

Comment: An elipse! Right?

Comment: @Карпатський Yes. That is what you are trying to find.

Comment: Thank you! What if insted of a sum were a difference?

Comment: @Карпатський Then you get a hyperbola.

Comment: Ok. But I assume I don't always have a reasonablebgeometric interpretation. Could you do itvalgebraicly please? So I can learn to operate them.

Comment: @Карпатський https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Cartesian_form_for_an_ellipse